# Location of Height in wordpress slider

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to decrease the size of the slider on my wordpress website:

////

The slider is 435 px, I did some research but can't find the location.

I did change the slider height in the style.css:

```
 #slider {
    position:relative;
    width:1000px;
    height:400px;
    background:url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
```

But it's still showing 435 px.

Anybody that could help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the html of the `#slider` div :

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider" style="position: relative; height: 435px; background-image: url(http://www.webgiants-im.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/internet_marketing_webgiants-im_2.jpg); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;">
```

You can see that there is a `height: 435px` in the markup, which by default takes precedence over styles defined in the .css file or in `<style></style>` blocks.

You can either mark the height as !important in your css file, which will force this value to be used :

```
#slider {
    position:relative;
    width:1000px;
    height:400px !important;
    background:url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

or remove the `height: 435px` from the html markup of the `#slider` div, or set it's value to 400px.

**EDIT** : To save you some troubles in the future, you should use web debugging tools like Firebug (for Firefox) or Chrome's development tools (I personnaly prefer the latter), these can be *very* useful. I think the keyboard shortcut to bring the browser's dev tools if F12 on most popular browsers.

Comment: Thank you very much! its working with !important :) I did see the 435px but couldnt find this 'html markup'. Do you know how to find this file? (for the learning process)

Comment: You're welcome, see my edit about web debugging tools. And dont forget to accept the answer if it helped you :)